# strange exception while consuming WCF Service (possibly character encoding exception?)

Tags: .net, wcf, http, character-encoding, windows-services

I am invoking a WCF service I made before , this service queries a semantic databse and returns dbpedia.org links, these links are with the names of the entities , so for example you would find "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama" or "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Brazil"

The problem I'm facing is that while invoking the method that returns the URIs mentioned, most of the time the method works, but rarely this error happens:

The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.RequestClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnRequest(TRequestChannel channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at ComparisonServiceInterface.Compare(String[] URIs)
   at ComparisonServiceInterfaceClient.Compare(String[] URIs)

Inner Exception:
The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

Inner Exception:
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)

Inner Exception:
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

I thinking that maybe some resources that have the different encoding, like "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sergio_Agüero" for the 'ü' character maybe or something ?

I tried encoding the uri before sending it back , it still throws the same exception.

The service Config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>  
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="mergedServices.MergedService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="mergedServices.RelationGeneratorServiceInterface">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="mergedServices.keywordSearchServiceInterface">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="mergedServices.QAServiceInterface">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="mergedServices.CompareWithOnePredicateServiceInterface">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="mergedServices.ComparisonServiceInterface">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="mergedServices.ProfileConstructorInterface">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/mergedServices/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

Comment: are you close chanel after every requst?

Comment: It's not clear if the problem is that you _always_ get this error when you use special characters ("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sergio_Agüero"), or if you just sometimes get this error, and have a guess that it might be special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily include exception detail in faults, this will allow you to get the real error.  Also, you should log exceptions before you rethrow them in you service, so you know what the real problem is without including exception detail in faults.

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
```

Comment: there's no exception happens from the server side, the exception happens in the transportation